# dompdf: base64 encoded SVGs aren't rendered correctly

Tags: svg, dompdf

I'm rendering a PDF in Symfony with dompdf.
`allow_url_fopen` is deactivated on my server. So I insert every image as base64-encoded.

```
    $imagesPath = "/var/www/project/web/print/img/"; 
    $images = array(
            "###FRONTPAGE###"   => $imagesPath . "company_frontpage_2016.svg",
            "###LOGO###"        => $imagesPath . "company_logo.svg"
    );

    foreach( $images as $image => $imageFile ) {

        if ( is_readable( $imageFile ) ) {
            $base64String = base64_encode( fread( fopen( $imageFile, "r" ), filesize( $imageFile ) ) );
            $html = str_replace( $image, "data:image/svg+xml;base64," . $base64String, $html );
        } else {
            $html = str_replace( $image, "File nicht lesbar", $html );
        }
    }
```

The absolute server path didn't work for me. Does anyone know a better solution for this?

I'm happy that I see the SVG in the PDF now. But they aren't rendered correctly. Any idea why?

Comment: How are the SVG documents rendered incorrectly? While SVG support is available in dompdf 0.7.0 it's mostly limited to shapes, text rendering still needs work.

Comment: Does the SVG display at all? @BrianS: I can't get inline SVG's to display at all :-( Which ways are supported?: <img src="file.svg"> or <svg> or <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,...">

Comment: If you're using v0.7.0 and have php-svg-lib available then they should display. Right now you have to use an image element to reference the SVG. So `<img src="file.svg">` or `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,...">` should work.

Comment: If you find an answer to this can you let me know. I am desperate to get svgs working in dompdf

Comment: @ThomasWilliams: I used a placeholder in my dompdf template. In the PHP Controller i replaced this dynamic through the base64 string. How i did this, you see in my post. Hope it helps you.